# Facebook authentication Android

Tags: java, android, facebook

So, here's my login function:

```
  public void facebookLogin()
{

    shareAppPreferences = new AppPreferences(getApplicationContext());
     facebook = ((GlobalVars)getApplicationContext()).facebook;

     String access_token = shareAppPreferences.getAccessToken();
     long expires = shareAppPreferences.getAccessExpires();
     Log.d("MyTag","token:" +access_token);
     if(access_token != null) {
         facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
     }
     if(expires != 0) {
         facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);
     }
     /*
      * Only call authorize if the access_token has expired.
      */
     if(!facebook.isSessionValid()) {
         Log.d("MyTag","In Authorize");
          facebook.authorize(this, new String[] {}, new DialogListener() {
              @Override
              public void onComplete(Bundle values) {
                //  new AccessKeyTask().execute("http://37.49.226.66/allaroundme/requests.php");
                  shareAppPreferences.saveAccessToken(facebook.getAccessToken());
                  Log.d("MyTag","face token: " +facebook.getAccessToken());
                  shareAppPreferences.saveAccessExpires(facebook.getAccessExpires());

              }

              @Override
              public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {}

              @Override
              public void onError(DialogError e) {}

              @Override
              public void onCancel() {}
          });
     }
     Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
     Log.d("MyTag", "starting activity");
     startActivity(intent);

}
```

I don't really understand why this code doesn't work, I logged out facebook via the facebook app before trying to use that code. the onComplete() seems not to happen and the access token is always null. but after my first login, I don't have to enter the info. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's code that worked for me:

```
    public void loginToFacebook(){
        facebook.authorize(CandyCount.this, new String[]{"publish_stream", "email"}, Facebook.FORCE_DIALOG_AUTH, new DialogListener() {

            public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onFacebookError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onError(DialogError e) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onError", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                Editor editor = sp.edit();
                editor.putString("access_token", facebook.getAccessToken());
                editor.putLong("access_expires", facebook.getAccessExpires());
                editor.commit();
                updateButtonStatus();

                getName();

            }

            public void onCancel() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

        });
    }
```

And in the onCreate:

```
    sp = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    access_token = sp.getString("access_token", null);
    expires = sp.getLong("access_expires", 0);
    getName = sp.getString("name", null);

    if (access_token != null){
        facebook.setAccessToken(access_token);
        fbName.setText("Hello, " + getName);
        updateButtonStatus();
    }
    if (expires != 0){
        facebook.setAccessExpires(expires);

    }
```

In the updateButtonStatus method I change the image of the button and in the onClick of the button I either sign out or log in according to whether session is valid.

Check out this [link](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xndi6s9Tn_U) it's pretty good in explaining the facebook sdk.

You just obviously would need to alter the code to fit your specific needs. I hope this helps!

Comment: Alright, so this code works just fine with saving the token: http://pastebin.com/Cm4QrG4B but if I logout my acc from the facebook app and then launch my app, it still remembers me, and doesn't require me to re-enter the facebook information. Do you see the problem ?

Comment: I believe that's how Facebook's access tokens are supposed to work. Once you provide your information and log in, then it can log you in automatically, though, it won't log you into facebook on other apps (such as the fb app). I logged out on the facebook app and then went in to my app, and indeed, it worked in automatically logging me in. Though, when I went back to the fb app I was logged out. That's just how it works